# Genuine/original pieces of clothing, accessories and devices

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, word-meaning, word-difference

What word **cannot** be used to identify whether a piece of clothing or an accessory or a device is **not fake**?

I know the words "genuine" and "original" and somehow I am aware how they differ in meaning. But I have no any idea how they can be used in the following sense in natural English.

Genuine--> not fake 
Original--> the first copy of something

> 1- These sunglasses are genuine / original. 
>   2- This t-shirt is a genuine / an original Givenchy. 
>   3- That mobile phone is a genuine / an original Vertu.

Are the constructions above correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, one can use the words "original", "authentic" and "genuine" all interchangeably and say e.g.

> This t-shirt is a/an (genuine / original / authentic) Givenchy.
>
> > The same goes for other examples of mine.